# DB2 saving a single table in database from rollback

Tags: db2, rollback, cobol, db2-luw

Is there any way in db2 to keep the rows of some tables saved while the rollback is performed.We have a situation in which system rolls back in case of error, but we have a requirement in which we need to save rows of 1 table while let others get rolled back.

Comment: Check out savepoints - they might help ...

Answer (score 1):

because you have tagged with COBOL I am assuming that you are using a program to do the inserts/updates.

After the rollback happens, just reinsert the one table you didn't want to roll back.

I don't think there is a way to do what you are requesting. A rollback always rolls back a unit of work. The only way to not roll back that table would be to do that insert or update first, then commit that unit of work THEN do all the stuff than can be rolled back.

Or you can use my first suggestion, if you are in a roll back situation have the program just re-insert/update what you want

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ability to use global-temporary-tables (created global temporary tables, or declared global temporary tables) then these can be defined with the characteristic "on rollback preserve rows".

This "on rollback preserve rows" can be useful for diagnostic and other purposes, but you need to take care of restartable-batch situations  and also watch for the  "with replace" option consequences.

In general however, if you need to have some rows saved, while others get rolled back then it suggests there is a flaw in your transaction design - maybe you need to have separate transactions (separate units of work), or different save points.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using autonomous transactions. This is a feature you put in the definition of the stored procedure. You just call a autonomous procedure in the same unit of work, and it separates the scope of the rollback.

You can see an example of this feature in log4db2, in a componente called appender that logs messages into table, even if there is a rollback. More or less what you need: https://github.com/angoca/log4db2/blob/master/src/main/sql-pl/04-Appenders.sql#L73